# is there are any worng element or missing element in the code?

Tags: html, css

I tried to implement the html and css but the close button is showing a square. There is nothing in the square but it works as a button

html:-

```
 <div class="alert-dismissible">
    <strong>Success!</strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['status2'];?>
    <button title="alert" type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
 </div
```

css:-

```
    .alert {
      position: absolute;
      top: 28px;
      right: 485px;
      width: 50px;
      padding: 1.25rem 1rem;
    }
    
    .alert-dismissible .close {
      position: absolute;
      top: -13px;
      right: 3px;
      z-index: 2;
      padding: 1.25rem 1rem;
    }
```

I have got this output:

[image]

Comment: Does this involve an existing CSS library such as, perhaps, bootstrap? If so, please add the tag for it to your question. Because, looking purely at the code you've posted, we can't get the output you're showing in your picture - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9mtcdbn3/ . Please ensure we have all the information we need in order to make a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I'm not entirely sure what you are asking for. What does `I want to visible the close button here in the square button box` mean, exactly? Perhaps showing us a picture of what you actually want would be helpful.

Comment: <button title="alert" type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button> you didn't write anything inside button tag how close will show?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have a well formed html code?

```
<div class="alert-dismissible">
    <strong>Success!</strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['status2'];?>
    <button title="alert" type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
 </div>
```

Comment: In the example you forget part of a tag

Comment: When you program in php you can see in the browser the web page source code in html to prove that is well formed

Comment: You realise you can [edit] your answer? You don't have to comment on your own post, just to add more information!